# How can Azure Devops get connected to kubernetes on an On-Premise Server with Rocky Linux 9

Tags: linux, kubernetes, azure-devops

we are going to connect Azure DevOps to kubernetes on a bare metal Server with rocky Linux 9 installed. The connection between Server and Azure DevOps is already done, now we got the challenge to get Azure Devops and Kubernetes connected. Has somebody an idea, in which form we can get the connetcion between k8s and Azure Devops?

Hello,

we are going to connect Azure DevOps to kubernetes on a bare metal Server with rocky Linux 9 installed. The connection between Server and Azure DevOps is already done, now we got the challenge to get Azure Devops and Kubernetes connected. Has somebody an idea, in which form we can get the connetcion between k8s and Azure Devops?

Answer (score 1):

On Azure DevOps, you can set up a [**Kubernetes service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#kubernetes-service-connection) to your Kubernetes.

Navigate to "**Project Settings**" > "**Service connections**" > "**New service connection**" button > select "**Kubernetes**".

Since your Kubernetes is hosted on your On-Premise Server, you can select "**`KubeConfig`**" or "**`Service Account`**" as the **Authentication method**. Then provide the required values following the notes on the window of the new service connection.

[image]

After the **Kubernetes service connection** is created successfully, you can use it in the pipelines via referencing its name to access the Kubernetes resources from pipelines on Azure DevOps.